# Improve SQL query to find range between start and end date

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with a database called `international_education` from the `world_bank_intl_education` dataset of `bigquery-public-data`.

```
FIELDS            
country_name      
country_code      
indicator_name    
indicator_code    
value   
year
```

My aim is to plot a line graph with countries who have had the biggest and smallest change in Population growth (annual %) (one of the `indicator_name` values).

I have done this below using two partitions finding the first and last value of the year by each country but I'm rough on my SQL and am wondering if there is a way to optimize this formula.

```
query = """
WITH differences AS
    (
    SELECT country_name, year, value, 
      FIRST_VALUE(value)
      OVER (
          PARTITION BY country_name
          ORDER BY year
          RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
      ) AS small_value,
      LAST_VALUE(value)
      OVER (
          PARTITION BY country_name
          ORDER BY year
          RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
      ) AS large_value
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education`
    WHERE indicator_name = 'Population growth (annual %)'
    ORDER BY year
    )
SELECT country_name, year, (large_value-small_value) AS total_range, value
FROM differences
ORDER BY total_range
        """
```

Convert to pandas dataframe.

```
df= wbed.query_to_pandas_safe(query)
df.head(10)
```

Resulting table.

```
    country_name            year    total_range value
0   United Arab Emirates    1970    -13.195183  14.446942
1   United Arab Emirates    1971    -13.195183  16.881671
2   United Arab Emirates    1972    -13.195183  17.689814
3   United Arab Emirates    1973    -13.195183  17.695296
4   United Arab Emirates    1974    -13.195183  17.125615
5   United Arab Emirates    1975    -13.195183  16.211873
6   United Arab Emirates    1976    -13.195183  15.450884
7   United Arab Emirates    1977    -13.195183  14.530119
8   United Arab Emirates    1978    -13.195183  13.033461
9   United Arab Emirates    1979    -13.195183  11.071306
```

I would then plot this with python as follows.

```
all_countries = df.groupby('country_name', as_index=False).max().sort_values(by='total_range').country_name.values

countries = np.concatenate((all_countries[:3], all_countries[-4:]))

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
sns.lineplot(x='year',y='value', data=df[df.country_name.isin(countries)], hue='country_name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the CTE and you don't need the window frame definitions.  So this should be equivalent:

```
SELECT country_name, year, value,
       (first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY YEAR DESC) -
        first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY YEAR)
       ) as total_range
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education`
WHERE indicator_name = 'Population growth (annual %)';
```

Note that `LAST_VALUE()` is finicky with window frame definitions.  So I routinely just use `FIRST_VALUE()` with the order by reversed.

If you want just one row per country, then you need aggregation.  BigQuery doesn't have "first" and "last" aggregation functions, but they are very easy to do with arrays:

```
SELECT country_name, 
       ((array_agg(value ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 1))[ordinal(1)] -
        (array_agg(value ORDER BY year LIMIT 1))[ordinal(1)]
       ) as total_range
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education`
WHERE indicator_name = 'Population growth (annual %)'
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY total_range;
```

Answer (score 2):

> thought there might have been a quicker way to write this query as seemed a bit long winded

I think below is the least verbose version (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  country_name, 
  year, 
  (LAST_VALUE(value) OVER(win) - FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER(win)) AS total_range, 
  value
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education`
WHERE indicator_name = 'Population growth (annual %)'
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY YEAR RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY total_range
```

... producing same result as your original query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to calculate, I wrote a query that do everything in BigQuery without the need to do anything in pandas.
This query returns all the rows for each country that rank top 3 or bottom 3 in change in Population growth.

```
WITH differences AS
(
SELECT
  country_name,
  year,
  value, 
  LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY year) - FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY year) AS total_range,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education`
WHERE indicator_name = 'Population growth (annual %)'
ORDER BY year
)
, differences_with_ranks as (
SELECT
  country_name,
  year,
  value,
  total_range,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY total_range) as rank,
FROM differences
)
, top_bottom  as (
SELECT
  country_name
FROM (
  SELECT
    country_name,
  FROM differences_with_ranks
  WHERE rank = 1
  ORDER BY total_range DESC
  LIMIT 3
  )
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
  country_name
FROM (
  SELECT
    country_name,
  FROM differences_with_ranks
  WHERE rank = 1
  ORDER BY total_range ASC
  LIMIT 3
  )
)
SELECT
  *
FROM differences
WHERE country_name in (SELECT country_name FROM top_bottom)
```

I don't really understand what do you mean with "optimize", this query run very fast (1.5 seconds) if you need a solution with lower latency BigQuery is not the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I suppose optimize is the wrong word. I meant a more succinct way to write the query. Only just getting back into some SQL and thought there might have been a quicker way to write this query as seemed a bit long winded.